# Mongodb fetch collections by java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am getting the following error:
    [image]

Program can't fetch collections attributes.

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));

        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("local");

        MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("sadi");

        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("name","amran");
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(searchQuery);
```

Comment: Please post a bigger picture. The one above is not readable.

Comment: Its an Incompatible types *Required com.mongodb.DBCursor Found com.mongodb.client.FindIterable*

Comment: So how to fetch 'sadi' collections attributes??

Comment: which version of java driver are you using ?

Comment: It may happen that you have imported wrongly. Check your mongo driver version for java and please update the question for  better understanding.

Comment: mongo-java-driver-3.1.0-20150623.222341-45.jar @dev

Comment: @S.M.AMRAN replace `MongoCollection` to `DBCollection`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
    import org.bson.Document;

    import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));

    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("local");

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("sadi");

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    searchQuery.put("name","amran");

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(searchQuery).iterator();  
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

As there are many changes in 3.0 series java driver related to database, collection,etc. Please go through [quick tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/) for more understanding.